# "family member's duty" vs. "the duty of the member of the family"

Tags: word-usage

When a friend and I were talking about children education, I said this to emphasize everyone should do chores.

> I’ve been working on having my son realize that doing chores is **duty of each member of the family**.

Should I have said it this way?

> ... doing chores is **each family member's duty**

Which appears to be shorter than the original.

Which one is more natural when speaking?

Answer (score 1):

Your fist example is not quite corret, as phrased. It shoudl be:

> I’ve been working on having my son realize that doing chores is the duty of each member of the family.

The word "the" is required before 'duty" in nthis construction.

Your alternate version

> I’ve been working on having my son realize that doing chores is each family member's duty.

conveys the same meaning. Each of these is grammatical and natural, the difference is purely one of style.  May would favor the second, slightly shorter, version. There are, of course, various other ways to express this idea.

Answer (score 0):

What I would say is: "doing chores is a family duty".

Comment: Thank you. Does this convey the idea clearly that everyone should do chores?

Comment: @JQQ  Not as clearly as your original, in my view